# Oracle Apps View: ALL_TAB_COLUMNS; columns: LOW_VALUE and HIGH_VALUE

Tags: schema, oracle-apps

What are the values in this View: ALL_TAB_COLUMNS view
columns: LOW_VALUE and HIGH_VALUE

I was hoping it would be the actual values in the in the view results.  I have a query that I use to find data sources for custom report development where this type of data would be very helpful.  Is there another table or view which would have the actual low value and high values?

It would be icing on the cake is this data exists.

Comment: Question revision:  Where the DATA_TYPE is NUMBER, how do I decode that into its actual number value?  See table values 2nd answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, these columns contain the actual high and low table values. They are used by the optimizer, collected by the gather statistics run.
The data is stored in raw format and you would need to convert it to see the actual values:

```
select
decode(dtc.data_type,'VARCHAR2',utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2(dtc.low_value)) low_value_char,
decode(dtc.data_type,'VARCHAR2',utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2(dtc.high_value)) high_value_char,
dtc.*
from
dba_tab_columns dtc
where
dtc.owner='AR' and
dtc.table_name='HZ_PARTIES'
```

Comment: The solution only seems to work on CHAR values. In my case the values I was most interested in are numeric.  The function returns a null value.

Comment: See my post below

Answer (score 0):

These are the results of the first solution provided.

[image: Results of the solution 1]

Comment: Question revision: Where the DATA_TYPE is NUMBER, how do I decode that into its actual number value? See table values 2nd answer.